# SVG content of Telerik RadHtmlChart

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net, telerik

Currently, I have an aspx page in vb that launches a RadHTMLChart and I want to grab the SVG code of that chart. However, since the chart is rendered client-side, I have to launch this aspx page and then grab the SVG code from a second aspx page during postback. Currently, I am using Server.Execute (firstpage.aspx) to grab the SVG code but this does not work. I want to use the SVG to generate a PDF document but the Server.Execute command seems to run in the background and the code that comes after it do not wait for it to finish first, hence I am not grabbing the SVG content. Does anyone know of another way to grab this SVG content?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need all of this done on the server, so you need to find a way to launch a browser on the server, get the needed data from it and close it. I think a tool called PhantomJS can do this for you, so you can give it a crack (it's free I think).

Here is an example on exporting an HtmlChart, but it relies on a user interaction (which can be automated via some scripts) but it needs the page opened on the client machine: http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/exporting-radhtmlchart-to-png-and-pdf. Anyway, it may still be helpful for ideas and to show how to get the SVG string.