# Server.Execute() does not wait for the second aspx page to finish executing?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have an aspx page that executes another aspx page through Server.Execute() since I need the called aspx page to postback in order to grab a session variable. However, I have noticed in my code that when the Server.Execute() is called, it does not wait for the called page to load up and posback, the code just goes on and the page is only loaded after the function is finished? Does anyone know how to fix this? Below is the code I am using in the parent page to call the page I want to load.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class TriggerPage
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Server.Execute("SvgForm.aspx", False)
    'This variable is only populated after the SvgForm.aspx executes and posts back since the Session variable is initialized there
    Dim htmlCode As String = Session("svgVariable")
End Sub

End Class
```

Aspx page code:

```
      <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="TriggerPage.aspx.vb" Inherits="TelerikChart.TriggerPage" %>

    <%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body onload="openWindow()">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
                <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js">
                    </asp:ScriptReference>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js">
                    </asp:ScriptReference>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js">
                    </asp:ScriptReference>
                </Scripts>
            </telerik:RadScriptManager>


            <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server"></telerik:RadWindowManager>

            <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock1" runat="server">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function openWindow() {
                        window.open('svgForm.aspx'); return false;
                    }

                    function RefreshParentPage() {
                        document.location.href = document.location.href;
                    }
                </script>
            </telerik:RadScriptBlock>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Looks like VB to me, not C#

Comment: asp.net is the same concept...

Comment: Why is this question tagged with telerik and javascript?

Comment: because the all telerik graphs are rendered as SVG and this is what I am grabbing and the postback is specifically related to javascript.

Comment: What makes you think that it's not waiting for the called page to finish?  If you're expecting the session variable to be set it won't be.  Server.Execute() is a completely different process therefore a new Session.

Comment: I put a break at End Sub, and I have nothing in the session variable, however, if I launch the program again after the window of the first page has executed once, then the session variable is populated, basically the aspx page that is called is not getting executed, it is only executed when the function is finished.

Comment: Using `Server.Execute()` in this manner is not a good idea. You're likely trying to use it for something it wasn't intended for. It's hard to tell because you haven't described what you're trying to accomplish, but using a generic handler (.ashx) might be useful here, or perhaps a web service such as Web API.

Comment: I am trying just to launch the first page, postback the rendered telerik chart svg code and put it in a session variable, and grab the session variable from that page and use the session variable in the caller page

Comment: I think that's what he is trying to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936749/svg-content-of-telerik-radhtmlchart
I hope my idea there will help. I have not used Server.Execute() and I can't help with this though.

Comment: @RickS Are you sure about new process for Server.Execute? According to sources of `HttpServerUtility` class it is executed in the same process using the same `HttpContext`, so it should have the same Session object!

Answer (score 0):

Tyger,

You are going about this wrong.  This is how one  captures the output html of a Server.Execute command:

```
Dim sw As New StringWriter()
Server.Execute("SvgForm.aspx", sw)
Dim htmlCode As String = sw.ToString
```

Be careful about passing data around as session variables.   I think I ran into troubles because Server.Execute() seems to cache replies into the context of the current session.   So subsequent changes to session variables may not lead to subsequent changes of the content generated by Server.Execute(), at least in the scope of the current user.  Although empirical, this is the only viable explanation for some rather crazy behavior I've seen.  Safer might be to append a random to the requested URI, to bust the cached session (user) specific response.

```
Server.Execute("SvgForm.aspx?rand=" & MyRandomNumberGenerator(), sw)
```

I'm going to test this theory to find out for sure...